# Tango - Unity - Depth: xyzij.color_image is now non-NULL! - But is only 900 bytes long?

Tags: google-project-tango

I noticed this morning with the "H" update for Tango Core that the Unity SDK is now seeing a "non-null" color_image returned from the Depth data!  Progress!

However it is only filled with 900 bytes of data?  Which is going to be a pretty tiny image. :)

Tango team :  Am I doing something wrong in the way I'm accessing the IntPtr in C#/Mono or is it still just too early to be actually getting color_images in Unity?

Code:

protected override void _OnDepthAvailable(IntPtr callbackContext, TangoXYZij xyzij)    {

```
            try {

                if(xyzij.color_image != null){

                    Debug.Log ("_OnDepthAvailable: Copying image");

                    //IntPtr timage = xyzij.color_image;

                    Debug.Log ("_OnDepthAvailable: Copying image 700");
                    //1280x720x3

                    int maxsize = 1280*720*4;
```

// I found mention in the stackoverflow questions that the expected images from C API are 1280x720x3 (? or 4=RGBA?)
//                      maxsize = 900;

```
                    lastimage = new byte[maxsize];

                for(int i=0;i<1280;i++){

                        byte b = Marshal.ReadByte(xyzij.color_image,i);

                        Debug.Log ("_OnDepthAvailable: i:"+i+" checking color_image: "+ b);

                    }
```

//  I get Debug.Log print outs up to 899 for every depth acquisition...

```
                    Marshal.Copy(xyzij.color_image,lastimage, 0, maxsize);
```

// My Marshal.Copy fails for any value larger than 900 for maxsize, but runs happily at 900

```
                    Debug.Log ("_OnDepthAvailable: Copying image 709");
                    string strRequest = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(lastimage);
```

//  tried to see if it was string being exported, it was just blank...

What am I missing here?

Comment: Agree that ain't likely an image, and have nothing else useful to add - if you discover that 900 bytes is meaningful, do let us know  :-)

Answer (score 0):

The color image buffer in the XYZij is currently not available, it is intend to be the time synced image. The 900 byte buffer might be just some artifacts in the memory.

Comment: I've noticed it is also present as non-null in the "I" release but again seems challenging to use as the size seems to be all over the place. Is there an update for color_image coming in the "I" Unity SDK? (So I should quit tinkering with it... and just be patient?)